# Is there a PHP script to replace post date with updated modified date

Tags: posts

I am looking for a PHP script that will change the date to date modified instead of the published date when I update a previous post or page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update post date to modified date automatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121565/update-post-date-to-modified-date-automatically)